# How to check if Unity container has already resolved a singleton type?

Tags: design-patterns, wpf-controls, unity-container

Given the following unity configuration:

```
<register type="MyProgram.IListDetailsView, MyProgram"
            mapTo="MyProgram.ListDetailsView, MyProgram"
            name="Contacts List">
    <lifetime type="singleton"/>
</register>
```

I want to do a check in code as follows:

```
bool firstCall = !container.ContainsInstance("Contacts List"))

IListDetailsView  listDetailsView = container.Resolve<IListDetailsView>("Contacts List");

if(firstCall)
{  
// do some work on listDetailsView
}
```

Is there an equivalent to this (made up) ContainsInstance method or some other way to get this state data? I want to check Unity references an instance, not that the type has been registered.

Comment: Please let us also know why you want to know whether or not a singleton has already been resolved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest then that you're doing something wrong.  UI components should be created and destroyed as needed.  If you really need to do this, then have a static boolean that indicates if your "do once" code has been run.  Again, do this in the constructor.  You'll need to lock in the constructor though if  you need to ensure thread safety.  Alternately, you can do work in the static ctor for your view details; .Net will ensure that is only run once the first time you access any static member.

Comment: In unity, there is a singleton for each named type ('Contacts List' but also others too) - so ListDetailsView itself is not a singleton as there are more than one instances of it; therefore, unfortunately, we cannot do the work in ListDetailsView's constructor.

Comment: Thanks Andy, I've already redesigned so that Contacts List etc derive from ListDetailsView and then I can use their constructors.

Answer (score 0):

I hope I didn't misunderstand your requirement. But for me it seems that you want to knwo when a view instance get's created to perform some initialization work. This is usually done using the constructor.

You register your view to unity. This does not create an instance of the view. The first resolve request for the type of the view makes unity create a new instance of the view. So all you have to do during the initializtation of the view can be done inside the constructor.

Comment: Thanks, but the particular (view) class is a base class that is used for several different views, so I cannot use its constructor as that could only construct one particular view. The idea is that I construct various views based on this base class e.g. a contacts view, inserting various user controls onto the base class (which contains a grid with 3 columns).

Comment: When it is a base class then you do not need to instanciate it anyway. Then all your code can go into the constructors of the derived classes.

Comment: Sorry, PVitt, I meant to write template rather than base class (although I couldn't edit my comment by the time I discovered this). So all different views are user controls inserted onto this template class (which contains a grid).

Comment: I think you have to provide more details to have your question answered. Please try to rewrite your question from scratch and describe your problem, not a possible solution.

Comment: Good idea, I've rewritten the question